# Where is saved a downloaded file with apache cordova

Tags: cordova

I download a pdf file using FileTransfer and display with a html link properly.

"cdvfile://localhost/persistent/test.pdf"

My idea is copy a remote folder recursive.

But where i "can see" downloaded files out of application, on my terminal or an utility?

Obs:

Im using Xcode to emulate IPAD.

Comment: If you using filetransfer plugin.then you specify the path.

Comment: The path is "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/test.pdf" but where is cdvfile path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered:

> file:///Users/joao.santos/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/6D9979AD-C3B7-4D09-A3FF-C7C2CD0DC4F3/